# How to list hidden targets in Phing

Tags: regex, xml, command-line, phing

My build.xml has 134 targets, most of which are hidden (hidden="true"). Is there a way to list all targets from the commandline? Target-definitions are sometimes split over multiple-lines, and I usually use double-quote-characters for properties. I'm running this on Debian, and kudos for sorting targets and/or also displaying descriptions. :-)

Examples:

```
    <target name="example1" hidden="false" />

    <target name="example3" hidden="true" />

    <target
        description="Ipsum lorem"
        hidden="true"
        name='example3'
    >
        <phingcall target="example1" />
    </target>
```

Comment: you might get more help if you add `xml` or `xmlstarlet` as a tag. I think this would be possible with `xmllint` and more certain that `xmlstarlet` can do it, but I'm not an expert. Good luck.

Comment: I'm thinking sed might be the way to go - but anything that can accept a regex would get me closer! (as would learning to _write_ regex *sigh*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't do this with Phing, but we can *within* Phing. There's probably a cleaner, better way than this, but this works - assuming all other properties are wrapped in double quotes (i.e. it *just* passes example#3, above)

```
<target name="list_all" hidden="false">
    <property name="command" value="
        cat ${phing.file.foo}
        | perl -pe 's|^\s*||g' 
        | perl -0pe 's|\n([^&lt;])| \1|gs'
        | grep '&lt;target'
        | perl -pe &quot;s|name='([^']*)'|name=\&quot;\1\&quot;|g&quot;
        | perl -pe 's|^&lt;target(\s?)||'
        | perl -pe 's|(.*)([ ]?)depends=&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;([ ]?)(.*)|\1 \2|g'
        | perl -pe 's|(.*)([ ]?)hidden=&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;([ ]?)(.*)|\1 \2|g'
        | perl -pe 's|.*description=&quot;([^&quot;]*).*name=&quot;([^&quot;]*).*|name=&quot;\2&quot; description=&quot;\1&quot;|g'
        | perl -pe 's|name=&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;|\1|g'
        | perl -pe 's|description=&quot;([^&quot;]*)&quot;|[\1]|g'
        | sort
        | uniq
    " override="true" />
    <exec command="${command}" passthru="true" />
</target>
```

What do those lines do?

1) output the contents of build.xml. Here, I'm interested in my 'global' build.xml which is named 'foo';

2) remove all leading whitespace from each line;

3) remove line-breaks *within* each opening tag;

4) filter for lines starting "<target";

5) change single quote-marks on name-property to double;

6, 7,8) remove leading "<target", and depends and hidden properties;

9) move 'description' *after* 'name' on each line;

10) remove 'name=' and its quote-marks;

11) replace 'description=' and its quote-marks with square-brackets; and

12, 13) sort & remove duplicates (if any)

Sample output:

```
    example1
    example2
    example3 [Ipsum lorem]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't with phing itself. The code simply skips the display if the target is set to "hidden".

Comment: Agreed. See my answer for an ExecTask-based approach